# PHP error upon installation

Tags: install

I keep getting this error when I go to install Craft: "Declaration of Craft\UrlManager::parseUrl() should be compatible with that of CUrlManager::parseUrl()"

I am installing on a subdomain.  The database credentials are in place, the permissions are correct and the craft folder is found.

I have devmode enabled and the last stack trace item is pointing to "craft/app/etc/web/UrlManager.php(18)".

Comment: Maybe some files weren't copied correctly, try re-uploading the /craft/app/ folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a bug in Craft that occurs with the specific configuration of PHP you're running.  Just fixed it for the next release, though.

In the meantime, you can open up craft/app/etc/web/UrlManager.php, find the parseUrl method and change it from:

```
public function parseUrl(HttpRequestService $request)
```

to:

```
public function parseUrl($request)
```